# How can I Download to CSV in Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j

I've been trying to download a certain data on my graph and it returns this error :
`Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected List<Node> but was Node (line 2, column 27 (offset: 77))"CALL apoc.export.csv.data(c,[], "contrib.csv",{})"`

This is the query I did :

`MATCH (c:Contrib) WHERE c.nationality CONTAINS "|"  CALL apoc.export.csv.data(c,[], "contrib.csv",{}) YIELD file, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize, batches, done, data RETURN file, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize, batches, done, data`

What went wrong ? :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the function: apoc.export.csv.data is

```
apoc.export.csv.data(nodes,rels,file,config)
```

- exports given nodes and relationships as csv to the provided file

The nodes is a collection of nodes rather than a node.

```
OLD: MATCH (c:Contrib) WHERE c.nationality CONTAINS "|" 
     CALL apoc.export.csv.data(c,[], "contrib.csv",{})

NEW: MATCH (c:Contrib) WHERE c.nationality CONTAINS "|" 
     WITH collect(c) as contribs
     CALL apoc.export.csv.data(contribs, [], "contrib.csv", {})
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I keep the "Yield" part though ? Or do I just run the code like that ?